# Placing matching occurrence number to the left side of the occurrence itself

Tags: regex, sorting, awk

I have a file with multiple occurrences of the expression ".mp3". I want the first occurrence to become "1.mp3", the second occurrence to become "2.mp3", and so on.

It would be something like awk '/ mp3 / NR' file

My file:

```
line 1
wget .mp3 url
line 2
wget .mp3

....
```

I haven't got any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/\.mp3/{sub(/\.mp3/,++count"&")} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thankx @RavinderSingh13!! It worked without problems!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'sub(/\.mp3/,c+1"&"){c++} 1' file
line 1
wget 1.mp3 url
line 2
wget 2.mp3
```

Comment: I was gonna post `{c+=sub(/\.mp3/,(c+1)"&")} 1`, ++

Comment: @oguzismail Sorry, I took a look but I haven't delved into creating gawk extensions so I don't have any feedback other than the comment I left under it.